# Remove level in a multidimensional array by replacing parent element with its subarray data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an multidimensional array.

```
{
    "id": "13",
    "name": "Example",
    "location_name": "NY",
    "phone": [
        {
            "number": "0617357707"
        }
    ],
    "facilities": {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "AC"
            },
            {
                "name": "Wi-Fi"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem I want to solve is at "facilities". Inside facilities, there is a data object. How can I remove the data without removing the content "data"?

Expected result:

```
{
    "id": "13",
    "name": "Example",
    "location_name": "NY",
    "phone": [
        {
            "number": "0617357707"
        }
    ],
    "facilities": [
        {
            "name": "AC"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wi-Fi"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried using `array_walk` or flatten but not getting it right.

Comment: Your json representation is wrong. It's neither an object nor an array. Is only the `facilities` relevant to your question? Is the `results` parts of an object or an array?

Comment: oh yes thanks for pointing. i copy from my fractal result so it got "results". @k0pernikus hi i've update with my answer. is it correct? yes i got my expected result. but should i keep doing that everytime i want to remove "data"?

Comment: Don't add answers within the question. And shouldn't you know if an answer works for you? ;) Your JSON is still broken. Check it here before posting: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @k0pernikus jsonlint said my json is valid. thanks.

Comment: The formatting implied differently. Fixed that for you.

Comment: oh the formatting. sorry. my real bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you could just do:

```
$results->facilities = $results->facilities->data
```

Working example:

```
<?php

$var = json_decode('{
    "id": "13",
    "name": "Example",
    "location_name": "NY",
    "phone": [
        { "number": "0617357707" }
    ],
    "facilities": {
        "data": [
            { "name": "AC" }, { "name": "Wi-Fi" }
        ]
    }
  }');
var_dump($var);

$var->facilities = $var->facilities->data;
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: not working. "Trying to get property of non-object". and if i do this, i won't get the other result right?

Comment: I've added a working example. Obviously, you should first check if 'facilities' and 'data' exists before accessing that data. From the error you're getting, I'd say that 'facilities' does not exist in one of your results.

Comment: Hi. i managed to answer slightly different from yours. $result['facilities'] = $result['facilities']['data']; i don't know why i keep getting "trying to get propery of non object" using yours

Comment: This answer is expecting an object while your actual data structure is an array. `json_decode` will turn JSON object into PHP object, while `json_encode` encode both associative array and object into JSON object.